how do you enable word wrap in dolphin when naming files
I would like to configure dolphin to wrap the file name text, instead of putting it on a new line. I have tried to do it through dolphins preferences, but had no success.
I find that being able to wrap the text for files, to be more aesthetically pleasing and it also, for me, works better in the browser window.
I can't seem to be able to enable this feature though. So I would like to know how to enable text wrap for my labels, and filenames.
